# Command using sed

Tags: sed

I have a problem. I want to change ole without changing dole in this file. I've tried to use:

```
sed -i s/^ole$/kari/ file.txt
```

Is there any way to change this without using two command lines as:

```
sed -i s/^ole/kari/ file.txt; sed -i s/ole$/kari/ file.txt
```

cat file.txt

```
ole duck
doffen duck
dole duck
duck, ole
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed -e s'/\bole\b/kari/g' file.txt`

`\b` boundary

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i.bak 's/\<ole\>/new_string/g' file.txt
```

In this case new_string would be kari (without quotes) if I understood correctly.

Comment: Thanks! What does the <> stand for?